# Autenticação usando Token Com Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autenticação, devise, token

Pessoal precisa de ajuda para implementar autenticação por **token**, já criei os models, a aplicação está funcionando corretamente, agora eu preciso melhorar a segurança.
A cliente vai me mandar matricula e uma senha, ela virá em `JSON`, tem um método que faz um select no banco para conferir se matricula e senha são true, eu gostaria de gerar um token uma vez por dia assim que matricula e senha forem confirmadas.Esse token vai retornar junto com o ID para o dispositivo , via `JSON`, e nas próximas operações todas serão validadas com esse token.

Esse é meu model que faz a consulta

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :simulated
    has_many :proof



        #Metodo que recebe matricula e senha para validar acesso

        def sqlValidatedLogin(registration,password)
        query_student = "SELECT id, name, token registration FROM students WHERE registration = "+
        registration+" AND password = "+password
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_student)
        end
end
```

#
metodo na controller

```
 def index
  student = Student.new
  return_dados = student.sqlValidatedLogin(params[:registration].to_s,params[:password].to_s)
  render :json => return_dados
  end
```

**Acesso para retornar os dados**

http://127.0.0.1:3000/students?registration=102030&password=%27123%27

Eu estou com dúvida de como implementar nas outras classes, li a documentação porem , não entendi a autenticação por token, alguém teria um exemplo de configuração com comentários, ou poderia me ajudar a implementar isso ?

Comment: Usei esse tutorial pra implementar um projeto e me atendeu muito bem
http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api

ele não utiliza do devise, as coisas são mais manuais, porem com uma eficacia substancial.